# python sql fetch data with dynamic updating conditions including variables

Tags: python, sql, hive

```py
from pyhive import hive  
cursor = hive.connect('XXX.XX.XX.XX').cursor()

import pandas as pd
def to_df(sql):
    cursor.execute(sql)
    return pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall()  , columns=[x[0] for x in cursor.description])

sql = '''
    select eventtype, count(truckid)
    from ods_intelli_truck.ods_intelli_truck_video_event_list_i_p_daily
    where 
    starttime > ({start_time}) 
    and starttime< ({end_time})
    and truckid in ({truck_id})
    group by eventtype
    limit 10
     '''.format(truck_id = truck_id, start_time = start_time, end_time = end_time)
```

i hope to select data from this database 'ods_intelli_truck.ods_intelli_truck_video_event_list_i_p_daily', with dynamiclly changing conditions, start_time, end_time and truki_id.
start_time, end_time and truki_id are three lists with same lengths.

how to make it work? thanks a lot